# How to query for followed user posts?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the posts from the users the current user is following. And also the post owners username and avatar.
My tables look like this

Users table

> User Id | Username | Avatar

Posts Table

> post_id | user_id | body | image

Follows Table

> leaders_id | followers_id

Here i s my current query

```
query = "SELECT *
            FROM posts
            WHERE $user_id IN(
                SELECT leader_id 
                FROM follows 
                WHERE follower_id=$user_id)
            ORDER BY date DESC
            LIMIT 10";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like as follows?

```
SELECT p.* FROM posts AS p, follows AS f 
WHERE p.user_id=f.leader_id AND f.followers_id=$user_id
```

If you want the `leader`s' information, you may join the `users` table.

```
SELECT p.*, u.* FROM posts AS p, follows AS f, users AS u 
WHERE p.user_id=f.leader_id AND p.user_id=u.user_id AND f.followers_id=$user_id
```

If you want the `follower`'s information, I would recommend you to use a separate query to `users` table, since the information would repeat in the query results otherwise.

Comment: Hey this seems to be working however I just realized I also need to query for some of the user details of the post owner, how would you query for that?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.* FROM posts p JOIN follows f ON p.userId = f.leaderId WHERE f.followerId = $userID;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c98df/3